# Apply awk command to all files in a directory

Tags: awk

I'm new in awk and I would like to apply a simple awk command to all files in a directory and get the result for each file separately.
The files are tab delimited and I just need to sum every value in column 11 and print the result separately for each file.  I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
for i in *;
do
awk -F '\t' '{sum += $11} END {print sum} "$i"'
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a simple typo in your shell quoting; this should work:

```bash
for f in *; do awk -F '\t' '{sum += $11} END {print sum}' -- "$f"; done
```

(the `--` is only necessary to protect against one of the filenames starting with a hyphen; a variable called `i` is usually integer by old Fortran convention so using one for a string is a little perverse); or alternatively

```bash
ls | while read -r f; do awk -F '\t' '{sum += $11} END {print sum}' -- "$f"; done
```

if you want avoid the risk of hitting the limit on the length of the command line (which is large but finite on current systems), though this will break if your filenames have newlines in them (why?!..).

If you want to do everything in a single Awk invocation, you can keep track of files using FNR (number of record inside file) and FILENAME:

```bash
awk -F '\t' 'FNR==1 {if (f) print sum; sum = 0; f = FILENAME} END {print sum} {sum += $11}' -- *
```

or alternatively (may invoke awk one or more times)

```bash
ls | xargs awk -F '\t' 'FNR==1 {if (f) print sum; sum = 0; f = FILENAME} END {print sum} {sum += $11}' --
```

with the same caveats as above.

You can guard against newlines in filenames by giving up on POSIX and using GNUisms which separate items with NULs (prohibited in filenames) instead of newlines (not prohibited), but unless your script is to run in a truly hostile environment it’s probably not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -F '\t' '{sum += $11} ENDFILE {print FILENAME ":", sum; sum=0}' *
```

`ENDFILE` block will run at the end of processing for each file where we are printing file name and sum.

---

If you don't have `gnu awk` then use this:

```sh
awk -F '\t' 'FNR==1 {if (sum) print fn ":", sum; sum=0; fn=FILENAME} 
{sum += $11} END {print fn ":", sum}' *
```

Comment: @PaulaO: Did you find anything wrong with this answer?